# How hashmap find bucket if hash code is greater then map size?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

I created one hashmap so default size will be 16. I overide the equals and hashcode method.  And I am returning 20 from hashcode method. So now we have bucket 0-15 in map but hashcode value is 20 so which bucket will be using  for insert this key?

Comment: The `HashMap` does not use the value returned by the `hashCode` methods directly. It uses them for some kind of modulo operation, using its own hashing method which obeys some nice mathematical properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
int i = Math.abs(hash % arr.size); // this always in this array
```

Comment: to be entirely correct `HashMap` *does not* uses `%`... hashCodes can be negative and negative module is a negative result - go find a negative bucket